# ControlTemplate to button with images - Silverlight for WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, user-controls, custom-controls, controltemplate

I have a ControlTemplate which targets a button control. The ControlTemplate has two images for the normal and pressed states, one for each. I want to use this ControlTemplate in 8 different buttons in the screen, each one with a diferent image in front of it.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonControlTemplate1" TargetType="Button">
        <Grid>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates1">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed1">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal1"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled1"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver1"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates1">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused1"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates"/>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates"/>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Image x:Name="image" Source="source1" />
            <Image x:Name="image1" Source="source2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

How can I put a third image inside the template that can receive a different source for each button?

Something like this:

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource ButtonControlTemplate1}" thirdImage="source_to_third_image"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use the Content property for your third image?

Your ControlTemplate will look like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonControlTemplate1" TargetType="Button">
    <Grid>
        ...
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        <Image x:Name="image" Source="source1" />
        <Image x:Name="image1" Source="source2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And your button declaration will look like this:

```
<Button>
    <Image Source="source3" />
</Button>
```

Then you just need to add a relevant visual state.

Comment: Yes, this is exatcly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand in your question, you're looking to implement [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265152%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Since the button itself does not carry properties for three separate image sources (you could hack around the `Content` property, but that would be a pain), you will need to implement those and simply perform standard binding from your template.